# Error during building an app in VSCode, A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'

Tags: cordova, build

I'm trying to build an app on visual studio code to my job, my VSCode was fully ok yesterday, building and working ok, but today it come with that error when I run this code "ionic cordova build android  ", can someone help me please? This is the error message:

```
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file 'D:\Fontes\AppCliente\Fontes\platforms\android\app\build.gradle' line: 113

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration 'classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:+.
     Required by:
         unspecified:unspecified:unspecified
      > No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.0-alpha03 was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a library compatible with Java 11, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.4.2' but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.0-alpha03 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a runtime of a component compatible with Java 11
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.4.2')
          - Variant 'javadocElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.0-alpha03 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 11)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.4.2')
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.0-alpha03 declares a runtime of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 11    
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.4.2')
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.0-alpha03 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 11)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.4.2')

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Command failed with exit code 1: D:\Fontes\AppCliente\Fontes\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b D:\Fontes\AppCliente\Fontes\platforms\android\build.gradle
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
```

I doesn't try anything yet, because the problem looks like version problems, and I'm afraid of desconfigure my desktop

Comment: Try to clean your build (cordova clean android)